# What is the recommended way to build a container component with multiple non-adjacent children?

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with a sidebar and a main section that looks something like this

```
|---------|--------------------------|
|         |                          |
|         |                          |
| sidebar |          main            |
|         |                          |
|         |                          |
|---------|--------------------------|
```

I've modularized this into the following component (excluding css for the sake of brevity).

```
export function ContainerWithSidebar({ sidebar, main }) {
  return (
    <div>

      <aside>
        { sidebar }
      </aside>

      <main>
        { main }
      </main>

    </div>
  )
}
```

So now I can use the component like this

```
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ContainerWithSidebar
      sidebar={
        <Navigation/>
      }
      main={
        <>
          <PostView
            postId={ postId }
            title={ post.title }
          />
          <Footer
            previousPage={ previousPage }
            nextPage={ nextPage }
          />
        </>
      }
    />
  )
}
```

This *works*, but it feels a bit awkward passing my children components in as props. I know I can do something like

```
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ContainerWithSidebar>
      <Navigation/>
      <>
        <PostView
          postId={ postId }
          title={ post.title }
        />
        <Footer
          previousPage={ previousPage }
          nextPage={ nextPage }
        />
      </>
    </ContainerWithSidebar>
  )
}
```

which looks much cleaner, but then I have to reference the children components by index as opposed to by name which feels like opening the door to bugs and confusion.

What is the preferred way to handle such a scenario?